# Proving $\frac{1-\exp(-2st)}{s}-\frac{t}{0.5+st}\geq(\sqrt{\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{s}} -\sqrt{ \frac{t}{1 + st}})^2$ for positive $s$ and $t$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the following

> $$\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{s} - \frac{t}{0.5 + st} \geq \left(\sqrt{\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{s}} -\sqrt{ \frac{t}{1 + st}} \right)^2 $$
> for $s>0$ and $t>0$.

I am able to simplify it, but not able to go beyond it. Following is the simplification.
$$\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{s} - \frac{t}{0.5 + st} \geq \frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{s} + \frac{t}{1 + st} - 2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{s}}\sqrt{ \frac{t}{1 + st}} \right) \\
\Rightarrow 2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{s}}\sqrt{ \frac{t}{1 + st}} \right) \geq \frac{t}{0.5 + st} + \frac{t}{1 + st} \\
\Rightarrow 4\left(\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{st} \frac{1}{1 + st} \right) \geq \left(\frac{1}{0.5 + st} + \frac{1}{1 + st}\right)^2
 $$
The last line comes after squaring.

Comment: Square and remove factor of $t$.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks! Made the edit.

Comment: That last line is wrong

Comment: @tomasliam Corrected it

Comment: You're still missing a factor of $t$

Comment: @DushyantSahoo this inequality doesn't even hold. Put $s=t=0.1$. And on the last line you are still missing a factor of $t$ on the RHS.